# ¿Como separar elementos de una ventana modal?

Tags: php, bootstrap, php8

Tengo un pequeño problema con una ventana modal,  Estoy poniendo tres cajas de texto en una misma fila, todo esta correctamente, muestra la información que requiero, pero el tema está en que todos los elementos que se ecuentran dentro de la ventana modal, se muestran juntos sin ninguna seperación, he probado varias opciones, pero no logro dar con la solución, espero Alguien que me pudiera ayudar para que los elementos queden separados Adjunto imagen de mi ventana modal y codigo del formulario.

Tengo un pequeño problema con una ventana modal,  Estoy poniendo tres cajas de texto en una misma fila, todo esta correctamente, muestra la información que requiero, pero el tema está en que todos los elementos que se ecuentran dentro de la ventana modal, se muestran juntos sin ninguna seperación, he probado varias opciones, pero no logro dar con la solución, espero Alguien que me pudiera ayudar para que los elementos queden separados Adjunto imagen de mi ventana modal y codigo del formulario.

[image: Modal con elementos juntos]

```html
<!--=====================================
MODAL AGREGAR CLIENTE
======================================-->

<div id="modalAgregarCliente" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <form role="form" method="post">

                <!--=====================================
                                 CABEZA DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar cliente</h4>

                </div>

                <!--=====================================
                            CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoCliente" name="nuevoCliente" placeholder="Ingresar nombre" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL PASSWORD -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>

                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoPassword" name="nuevoPassword" placeholder="Ingresar password" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        


                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL RFC -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoRfc" name="nuevoRfc" placeholder="Ingresar RFC" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL CURP-->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoCurp" name="nuevoCurp" placeholder="Ingresar CURP" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL EMAIL -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>

                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoEmail" name="nuevoEmail" placeholder="Ingresar email" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA LA DIRECCIÓN -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaDireccion" name="nuevaDireccion" placeholder="Ingresar dirección" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL RUBRO -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-registered"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevoRubro" name="nuevoRubro" placeholder="Ingresar Rubro" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR REGIMEN -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>

                                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaCategoria" name="nuevaCategoria" required>

                                    <option value="">Selecionar Regimen</option>

                                    <?php

                                    $item = null;
                                    $valor = null;

                                    $categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                                    foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                                        echo '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["categoria"] . '</option>';
                                    }

                                    ?>

                                </select>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR BANCO -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>

                                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaCategoriaBanco" name="nuevaCategoriaBanco" required>

                                    <option value="">Selecionar Banco</option>

                                    <?php

                                    $item = null;
                                    $valor = null;

                                    $categoriaBancos = ControladorCategoriaBancos::ctrMostrarCategoriaBancos($item, $valor);

                                    foreach ($categoriaBancos as $key => $value) {

                                        echo '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["banco"] . '</option>';
                                    }

                                    ?>


                                </select>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA NUMERO DE CUENTA-->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>

                                <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaCuenta" name="nuevaCuenta" placeholder="Ingresar Número de cuenta" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA CUENTA CLABE-->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt"></i></span>

                                <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaCuentaClabe" name="nuevaCuentaClabe" placeholder="Ingresar Clabe Interbancaría" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA REGISTRO PATRONAL-->

                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaRP" name="nuevaRP" placeholder="Ingresar Registro Patronal" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--=====================================
                    PIE DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cliente</button>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No indicas lo que has probado, pero lo que necesitas es espaciado vertical. Puedes añadirlo a todas tus `<div class="col-sm4">` con:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 my-2">
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, tambien he probado esa manera pero aun asi no siguen todo junto los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Encotre la solución agregue `<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]